# Car shakes since replaced spark plugs

Tags: sparkplugs, ignition-coil, lincoln

I have a 2011 Lincoln MKZ and I just replaced the spark plugs and now the car shakes and Im getting a obd reading P0351- Ignition Coil A primary/secondary circuit
P0113- Intake Air Temp Sensor 1 Circuit High

And the car shakes while driving. A friend and I replaced them then before doing a reading on it, my friend said I need to get a new MAF sensor so I drove 35 miles back to my home town with car driving like crap and went and spent 79 on one. I now just did the reading and now need to know what I need to do ? I haven't replaced the MAF sensor yet. Is it the MAF I need to replace. Any ideas what I need to do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like either one of the coils has gone bad (less likely) or you didn't get one reconnected all the way (more likely). This can happen due to the plug or if a ground isn't working like it should be. Considering the code, it is very plausible you didn't get a connector reattached correctly (seated correctly or not attached at all). Take a look at your work. I'll bet that's where the problem lies with how it is running. You could also try just pulling the connector and reseating all of them.

Do NOT replace the MAF. It is doubtful this has anything to do with anything. I see you stated you have a second code, but this really wouldn't have anything to do with a MAF. When you've double checked your work on the coils, clear the codes and see if the P0113 comes back. If it does, you should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Thank you for your help Im going to return the sensor today and check the connection praying thats all it is because I cant afford to take it anywhere.